# Pass a struct to an UDAF in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have the following schema -

```
root
 |-- id:string (nullable = false)
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- cars: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- car1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- car2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- car3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

How can I pass the struct 'cars' to an udaf? What should be the inputSchema if i just want to pass the cars sub-struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, but the logic of the UDAF would be different. For example, if you have two rows:

```
val seq = Seq(cars(cars_schema("car1", "car2", "car3")), (cars(cars_schema("car1", "car2", "car3"))))

val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(seq)
```

Here the schema is

```
root
 |-- cars: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- car1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- car2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- car3: string (nullable = true)
```

then if you try to call the aggregation:

```
val df = seq.toDF
df.agg(agg0(col("cars")))
```

You must change your UDAFs input schema like:

```
val carsSchema =
    StructType(List(StructField("car1", StringType, true), StructField("car2", StringType, true), StructField("car3", StringType, true)))
```

and in the boy of your UDAF you must deal with this schema changing the inputSchema:

```
override def inputSchema: StructType = StructType(StructField("input", carsSchema) :: Nil)
```

In your update method you must deal with the format of your input Rows:

```
override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
  val i = input.getAs[Array[Array[String]]](0)
  // i here would be [car1,car2,car3],  an array of strings
  buffer(0) = ???
}
```

An from here, you can transform i to update your buffer and complete the merge and evaluate functions.

Comment: Thanks. This really helps. Is there any better way to extract values from input other than using get* methods?