# Spark UDAF dynamic input schema handling

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I know how to pass a struct with inner struct to a UDAF from this -
[Pass a struct to an UDAF in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54518102/pass-a-struct-to-an-udaf-in-spark)

But how do I handle cases where the inner struct schema is unknown or dynamic in the sense that it changes based on the data. Some of the fields may or may not exists as the input data does not adhere to a specific schema. Let's say one data set has

```
   root
     |-- id:string (nullable = false)
     |-- age: long (nullable = true)
     |-- cars: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- car1: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- car2: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- car3: string (nullable = true)
     |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

And the other data set does not have *car3*

```
root
 |-- id:string (nullable = false)
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- cars: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- car1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- car2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

How do I write a UDAF that accepts the schema that changes based on the input data.

Comment: Interesting question. Would you be able to transform your cars schema into for example ArrayType(String) and adapt your UDAF to use it? Then you can have variable number of elements in it.

Comment: I have figured out a way to deal with it by making schema passed through initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema can be passed dynamically while initializing the Udaf class -

```
    val yetAnotherUdaf = new YetAnotherUdaf(schema)

    case class YetAnotherUdaf(schema:StructType) extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {

      override def deterministic:Boolean=true
      override def dataType:DataType=schema
      override def inputSchema:StructType=schema
      override def bufferSchema:StructType=schema

      override def initialize(buffer:MutableAggregationBuffer):Unit={ ??? }
      override def update(buffer:MutableAggregationBuffer, input:Row):Unit={ ??? }
      override def merge(buffer1:MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2:Row):Unit={???}
      override def evaluate(buffer:Row):StructType={ ??? }
   }
```